# how can i download big files using retrofit v1.9 ?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

all examples i can see are using v2.x to download big files something like this

```
@Streaming
@GET("/endpointHere")
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Query("name") String video);
```

but that ResponseBody is not there in V1.9 ? so how can i use v1.9 to download files? upgrading to v2.x is not in option for some reasons.
Help me , thanks!

Comment: I am more curious as to what are those reasons that upgrading to newer version is not possible. Ussually it is a common practise to do so, if the library is actually released with the version (so not a test release).

Comment: actually i'm adding some extra functionality to an existing android app .... they were using retrofit v1.9... now i changed it to v2.1 and that is causing me to make lot of changes in code... i want to avoid that..  
Is there something i can do without upgrading?